# Oauth2 cannot request to login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring 2.3.12.RELEASE with Hoxton.SR11 as cloud version. The dependency I'm using is spring-cloud-starter-oauth2.

I just configure all the oauth server but when I'm trying to do login I get a 401 response. I think that I'm missing something but I cannot fix it.

Here is the code:
AuthoritationServerConfig

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthoritationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticacionManager;

    @Autowired
    private InfoAdicionalToken infoAdicionalToken;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.id"))
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.secret")))
                .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(infoAdicionalToken, accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticacionManager)
        .tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.jwt.key"));
        return tokenConverter;
    }

}
```

SpringSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService usuarioService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

ResourceServerConfig

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${config.security.oauth.jwt.key}")
    private String jwtKey;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/security/oauth/**").permitAll();
        
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey(jwtKey);
        return tokenConverter;
    }
```

Zuul application properties

```
zuul.routes.security.service-id=servicio-oauth
zuul.routes.security.path=/api/security/**
zuul.routes.security.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

This is a capture of the request:
[image: Request login]

Request headers:
[image: Request headers]

Response headers:
[image: Response headers]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please add response headers?

Comment: @geobreze I update the post to add the request headers nd the response headers

Comment: I think, for this configuration, you should be using grant type `client_credentials` and pass `config.security.oauth.client.id` as `client_id` and  `config.security.oauth.client.secret` as `client_secret`. Also, you're sending `client_id` and `client_secret` via Basic Auth, so adding `client_credentials` to allowed grant types  and sending this grant type in request body may help.

Comment: What did you mean when you say config.security.oauth.client.id as client_id and config.security.oauth.client.secret as client_secret? Those is not the withClient and secret methods? I add `client_credentials` to `authorizedGrantTypes` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean their values, which are you using in `withClient` and `secret` methods

Comment: The values I'm passing in the Basic Authorization.

Comment: Right, so you should try changing `authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")` to `authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")` and `grant_type` in Postman from `password` to `client_credentials`.

Comment: I'm still getting 401 with this change.

Comment: One more thing I can recommend is to try replacing `passwordEncoder.encode(env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.secret"))` with just `env.getProperty("config.security.oauth.client.secret")`.

Comment: I just try it but it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong.